# Go Live, Live Server, Vs Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Eu coloquei a extensão Live Server no meu VS Code para que a minha página de internet atualize automaticamente enquanto eu digite o meu código.

De vez em quando aparece o botão "Go Live" para que eu possa ligar o Live Server e de vez em quando não aparece o botão.

Alguém sabe como ligar o "Go Live" quando não aparece este botão ?

Answer (score 0):

clique com o botão direito no arquivo html que você quer abrir e clique na opção "abrir com o Live server".
Caso essa opção nao apareça reinicie o VScode

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar os atalhos:
*Alt+L* ou *Alt+O* para começar o Live Server.
Abrir arquivos diretamente também pode fazer com que o botão não apareça, então procure abrir sempre a pasta do projeto.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).